# TIKZ: only fill 75% of the node-background with color

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, tikz-styles, backgrounds

I want to use some background color on my node, but not for the whole node. Just for 75% of the node.

My code is this:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz\node[draw, fill=gray!30]{Some Text};
\end{document}
```

Which produces this:

[image]

But I want more something like this:

[image]

Edit: The white and the grey part should be reversed in the second image.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use `path picture` and `path picture bounding box`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\tikz
\node[draw]
  [path picture={
    \fill[gray!30](path picture bounding box.north west)rectangle
        ($(path picture bounding box.north east)!.75!(path picture bounding box.south east)$);
  }](n)
  {Some Text}
;
\end{document}
```

[image]

This works also if the node is a `circle`:

[image]

or a `cloud` (options: `cloud,cloud ignores aspect`, needs library `shapes.symbols`):

[image]

Only if the node is a rectangle, you can use the node name instead `path picture bounding box`:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\tikz
\node[draw]
  [path picture={
    \fill[gray!30](n.north west)rectangle($(n.north east)!.75!(n.south east)$);
  }](n)
  {Some Text}
;
\end{document}
```

---

**Update** (because of a comment)

If the background should be colored in an intervall, eg. from 0.3 to 0.8, use

```
($(<name>.north west)!.3!(<name>.south west)$)
rectangle
($(<name>.north east)!.8!(<name>.south east)$);
```

Replace `<name>` by the node name or `path picture bounding box`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\tikz
\node[draw]
  [path picture={
    \fill[gray!30]
      ($(path picture bounding box.north west)!.3!(path picture bounding box.south west)$)
      rectangle
      ($(path picture bounding box.north east)!.8!(path picture bounding box.south east)$);
  }](n)
  {Some Text}
;
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, thats it! How can i define an specific intervall? i.e. 'just color the background from 0.8 till 0.3 gray'

Comment: @ipo See the example at the end of my updated answer.

Answer (score 14):

Doing the fill in a separate step might be an option.

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,backgrounds,scopes}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node[draw] (a) {Some Text};
{ [on background layer]
\fill[gray!30] (a.north west) rectangle ($(a.south east)!0.3!(a.north east)$);
}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Oops, that `0.3` should of course be `0.25`.

Answer (score 8):

I propose something similar: shading

```
\documentclass[tikz,margin=5mm]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\tikz\node[draw, top color=gray!30,bottom color=white]{Some Text};
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**

Since it was requested, here is a sample with a fading; I set the background as orange, in order to make the effect apparent

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pagecolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pagecolor{yellow!30!orange}
\usetikzlibrary{fadings} 
\begin{document}

\tikzfading[name=fade down,
top color=transparent!0,
bottom color=transparent!100]

\begin{tikzpicture}[path fading=fade down]
\node[draw, fill=gray!30,path fading]{Some Text};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

With result:

[image]

Comment: Is there also a way to make the color transparent? And i don't mean white. i.e. `top color=white!30,bottom color=none`

Comment: @ipo you should look into fadings, I give only an example